# iw not allowing me to create interface (invalid exchange -52)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, network-monitoring

Kali linux on a Raspberry Pi 4B, adding a monitor interface using `iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor` gives `command failed: invalid exchange (-52)`.

iw list:

```
Wiphy phy0
        wiphy index: 0
        max # scan SSIDs: 10
        max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
        max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
        max # match sets: 16
        Retry short limit: 7
        Retry long limit: 4
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports roaming.
        Device supports T-DLS.
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
                * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * monitor
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x1062
                        HT20/HT40
                        Static SM Power Save
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        No RX STBC
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
                        * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Band 2:
                Capabilities: 0x1062
                        HT20/HT40
                        Static SM Power Save
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        No RX STBC
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
                VHT Capabilities (0x00001020):
                        Max MPDU length: 3895
                        Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
                        short GI (80 MHz)
                        SU Beamformee
                VHT RX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: not supported
                        3 streams: not supported
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
                VHT TX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: not supported
                        3 streams: not supported
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
                VHT extended NSS: not supported
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5190 MHz [38] (disabled)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5210 MHz [42] (disabled)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5230 MHz [46] (disabled)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5720 MHz [144] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm)
        Supported commands:
                 * new_interface
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * start_ap
                 * join_ibss
                 * set_pmksa
                 * del_pmksa
                 * flush_pmksa
                 * remain_on_channel
                 * frame
                 * set_wiphy_netns
                 * set_channel
                 * tdls_oper
                 * start_sched_scan
                 * start_p2p_device
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
                 * crit_protocol_start
                 * crit_protocol_stop
                 * update_connect_params
        software interface modes (can always be added):
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ monitor } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 4, #channels <= 2
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
                   total <= 4, #channels <= 1
        Device supports scan flush.
        Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
        max # scan plans: 1
        max scan plan interval: 508
        max scan plan iterations: 0
        Supported TX frame types:
                 * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * managed: 0x40 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
        Supported extended features:
                * [ CQM_RSSI_LIST ]: multiple CQM_RSSI_THOLD records
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_PSK ]: 4-way handshake with PSK in station mode
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_1X ]: 4-way handshake with 802.1X in station mode
                * [ DFS_OFFLOAD ]: DFS offload
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_AP_PSK ]: AP mode PSK offload support
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.136  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2601:644:8000:7cb0:da3a:ddff:fe4a:d95c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::da3a:ddff:fe4a:d95c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:4a:d9:5c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6242  bytes 777550 (759.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 533  bytes 101632 (99.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 80  bytes 6480 (6.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 80  bytes 6480 (6.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.133  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2601:644:8000:7cb0::af44  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2601:644:8000:7cb0:147a:cfce:1d81:27fc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::cb43:3dd5:3ac3:59b3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:4a:d9:5d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3305  bytes 528814 (516.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1576  bytes 240534 (234.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Can you check `dmesg` for any messages that show up when you try to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the places where the Broadcom 'brcmfmac' driver returns `-EBADE` is annotated with a comment "PROMISC unsupported by firmware of older chips" (your kernel logs in `dmesg` might have an error message confirming this). Since promiscuous mode would be a subset of the functionality needed for monitor mode, it implies that monitor mode is also unsupported by older Broadcom chips. Various posts on the Internet also seem to confirm that the Wi-Fi chip on Raspberry Pi 4 does not support monitor mode (despite your `iw phy` saying that it does).

Comment: I checked dmesg - I found `[22419.252306] brcmfmac: brcmf_vif_add_validate: Attempt to add a MONITOR interface...
[22419.252356] brcmfmac: brcmf_mon_add_vif: brcmf_mon_add_vif called
[22419.252373] brcmfmac: brcmf_mon_add_vif: Adding vif "mon0"
[22419.253296] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_request_ap_if: setting ssid failed -52`